# Expose all image attachments for custom object

Tags: lightning, attachment, images

I have a custom object that has "Group Events." These are events our org runs that have one or more partner accounts (i.e. someone who hosted the event or helped pay for the event space), featured speaker contacts, etc.

After events happen we're having the event organizers upload photos as attachments to the "Group Event" alongside things like PDFs of flyers and agendas for the event. Most events will have photos of the event, but not all of them.

I want to allow our designer to login to Salesforce and be able to find the latest photos of events, as well as list events that have photos attached.

What would be the best way to expose this data to him inside Salesforce? For example, is there a way to list inside Salesforce all photos for a custom object type, or list all custom objects that have attachments that are JPEGs?

We're using lightning.

Comment: have you tried querying for the created records  in the past 24 hrs (for example) that have attachments of type jpeg?

Comment: Yep, that works fine. The problem is not how to query the data, the problem is how do I expose it inside the Salesforce UI

Comment: by creating a lightning component? if you are asking how to create one, this is very well documented and you can learn how to do so at [Trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en)

Comment: If you do encoutner any issues while creating your lightning component, feel free to open a new post within the scope defined in the [help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily fetch the data using a query for created records from the past 24 hours that have attachments of type JPEG, afterwards, you might want to create a lightning component in order to display those records for your designer to check.

There is plenty of documentation that can help you achieve this, I would recommend you start out by doing the [Lightning Components Basics Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics) module.

As well as refer you to the [Lightning Components Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/intro_framework.htm)

If you do encounter any issues while creating your lightning component, feel free to open a new post within the scope defined in the [help center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help)